# Which file has a definition of add_post_meta function?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know which file I can find the definition of add_post_meta function in wordpress 3.0?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the files, have you tried searching in the files? Most modern OSs let you search the contents of files.

Comment: Or use an Xref, or the documentation, or any number of different tools on the internet. I'm not going to downvote, but it's a pretty silly question to ask.

Comment: I tried with grep command...didnt find somehow...Sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  It's defined in `/wp-includes/post.php` at line 1151.